# WWW::Mechanize ssl cross-site login failure cookie_jar not populating

Tags: perl, authentication, ssl, mechanize, www-mechanize

The URL $url, redirects to https://auth.outside.com/secure/login for authentication over SSL. The site stores some cookie, as soon as you land on the page, and also some on successful authentication. However, I am not getting the cookie file populated, even when i manage to land on the page. this is an example with google, but real URL is different.

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Crypt::SSLeay;
use HTTP::Cookies;


my $userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0';
my $cookie_file = 'auth_cookies.txt';
$ENV{HTTPS_PROXY} = 'http://myproxy.net:8080';

my $google='https://www.google.com';

my $url = $google;
my $tempfile='download_details';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(
    noproxy => 0,
    agent => $userAgent,
    cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies->new( file => $cookie_file )
    );

my $result=$mech->get( $url, ':content_file' => $tempfile );
print sprintf( "User-Agent %s\n  redirects to: %s\n\n", $userAgent, $mech->uri() );
print "result=$result\n";
```

**outputs following:**

User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
  redirects to: https://www.google.com

result=HTTP::Response=HASH(0x3474ef0)

**but** does not create any cookie file even thou i can see a bunch of cookies in firebug.

Comment: Re "The proxy is reachable from the CLI", so how do you call the script when it doesn't work?

Comment: from CLI only. it seems the remote site is rejecting the connection attempt, but i do not know for sure. any way to print what is being returned if anything?

Comment: look at the response with `print $response->as_string`

Answer (score 1):

after adding this code, the file is populating...

```
$mech->cookie_jar->set_cookie(
    qw(
        3
        cat
        buster
        /
        .example.com
        0
        0
        0
    )
);
```